# Vector Parametric Form Flat

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, vectorization

Please see the image with the question and my answer. The thing I'm having an issue with is understanding what this vector description actually is. Is it a 2-dimensional flat in $\mathbb{R}^6$?

In fact, according to the table, we have
$n-2$ Cartesian equations and $2$ free parameters in this example. So since $n−2=4$ then $n=6$? Is this true?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this post. Really appreciate your help.

[image: Question Image with my answer]

Comment: Great thanks, and it is in $\mathbb{R}^6$?

Comment: Thanks, looking at Table 3 would suggest that it's in $\mathbb {R}^6$ as there are four Cartesian equations and 2 free parameters. Is there something wrong with Table 3 or the way I'm interpreting it?

Comment: n-2 Cartesian equations and 2 free parameters. So since $n-2=4$ then $n=6$?

Comment: Oh I see; so to work out which space it is in I just need to know how many variables there are? Since there are 5, it's in R^5?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table constructs a formula between the number of free parameters $F$, number of equations $E$, and the dimension of the space $n$ as follows

$$n-F=E\tag{1}$$

however, it should be emphasized that $E$ is the number of **linearly independent equations** and not just the number of equations! Now, let us see how many linearly independent equations we have in your example. For doing so we may perform the usual elementary row operations on the system of equations. This can easily be done with the augmented matrix

\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1  & 0  & 3  & 2  & 0  &  8\\
0  & 0  & 1  & 0  & 2  &  4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  2\\
3 & 0 & 8 & 5 & -3 & 18
\end{array}
\right]
&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1  & 0  & 3  & 2  & 0  &  8\\
3 & 0 & 8 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & 0  & 2  &  4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\\
&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1  & 0  & 3  & 2  & 0  &  8\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & 0  & 2  &  4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\\
&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1  & 0  & 3  & 2  & 0  &  8\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 2 \\
0  & 0  & 0  & \frac{1}{3}  & \frac{1}{3}  &  \frac{2}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\\
\end{align}

So as we can see there are just $3$ linearly independent equations in your example as the last row turned out to be zero. So in your example we will get

\begin{align}
F&=2 \\
E&=3 \\
n&=F+E=5
\end{align}

> However, when you want the dimension of the space you are working in, you can simply look at the number of variables in the equations.

The formula $(1)$ is a simple manifestation of the rank-nullity theorem which you may study in a course dealing with theoretical aspects of linear algebra.

Comment: @Andy: you're welcome. :)